# eclipse 4 application part not appear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to learn eclipse 4 application development, I add a part my application through the application model, but the part does't show itself.
[image]
the part class:

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class ObjectEditor {
    @Inject
    public ObjectEditor(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("hello e4");
    }



    @Focus
    public void onFocus() {
        //TODO Your code here
    }


}
```

what's wrong ?
**Edit---------------------------------------------------------------------**

I  have found that, the workbench.xmi in the runtime folder of my project is not updated after I changed application model(the Application.e4xmi file), what step did I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add to add `-clearPersistedState` to the program arguments of your launch configuration?